# Tiger geocoder is not finding results from manually loaded tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geocoding, tiger

I'm trying to test the TIGER geocoder with the address provided in the [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/Geocode.html).

This is the sample address I'm testing:`75 State Street, Boston MA 02109`

```
SELECT g.rating, ST_X(g.geomout) As lon, ST_Y(g.geomout) As lat,
    (addy).address As stno, (addy).streetname As street,
    (addy).streettypeabbrev As styp, (addy).location As city, (addy).stateabbrev As st,(addy).zip
    FROM geocode('75 State Street, Boston MA 02109') As g;
```

But I'm not getting any match for this query:

[image]

I have installed PostgreeSQL, PostGIS and the requerired extensions:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
--this one is optional if you want to use the rules based standardizer (pagc_normalize_address)
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

Also I have also downloaded the data corresponding to that address from the census [site](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php), which is correspondes to the state of MA (suffolk_county)

I have loaded the data into a table using the following comand:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:dbname=test1 -progress -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI /GIS/data/ma_suffolk_county/tl_2016_25025_edges.shp -nln ma_suffolk_county
```

The table was succesfully created:

```
\d+ ma_suffolk_county
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:dbname=test1 -progress -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI /GIS/data/ma_suffolk_county/tl_2016_25025_edges.shp -nln ma_suffolk_county
```

This is not how you load the data. Follow the section entitled [*Installing, Upgrading Tiger Geocoder and loading data*](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder). You can not diverge from these instructions at all.

Comment: I was following that until step 2.8.4 then I had some issues. Is this because I'm not indexing the data doing it this way? or what is the issue?

Comment: You load the data by running the scripts you generate with `Loader_Generate_Nation_Script` and `Loader_Generate_Script`. You do not use `ogr2ogr`